# How to count the occurences of a word in a row

Tags: r, string, count, frequency

I have a row of strings like this :

```
[1] X                                             Royal.Perth.Hospital                         
[3] X.1                                           X.2                                          
[5] X.3                                           X.4                                          
[7] X.5                                           X.6                                          
[9] Fremantle.Hospital                            X.7                                          
[11] X.8                                          X.9                                          
[13] X.10                                         X.11                                         
[15] X.12                                          
Princess.Margaret.Hospital.For.Children      
[17] X.13                                         X.14                                         
[19] X.15                                          X.16                                         
[21] X.17                                          X.18                                         
[23] King.Edward.Memorial.Hospital.For.Women       X.19                                         
[25] X.20                                          X.21                                         
[27] X.22                                          X.23                                         
[29] X.24                                          Sir.Charles.Gairdner.Hospital                
[31] X.25                                          X.26                                         
[33] X.27                                          X.28                                         
[35] X.29                                          X.30                                         
[37] Armadale.Kelmscott.District.Memorial.Hospital X.31                                         
[39] X.32                                          X.33                                         
[41] X.34                                          X.35                                         
[43] X.36                                          Swan.District.Hospital                       
[45] X.37                                          X.38                                         
[47] X.39                                          X.40                                         
[49] X.41                                          X.42                                         
[51] Rockingham.General.Hospital                   X.43                                         
[53] X.44                                          X.45                                         
[55] X.46                                          X.47                                         
[57] X.48                                          Joondalup.Health.Campus                      
[59] X.49                                          X.50                                         
[61] X.51                                          X.52                                         
[63] X.53                                          X.54
```

I want to count the number of times the word Hospital occured in the row. 
Note: the last hospital does not have the word "hospital" in it's name instead it has a 'health campus' in it's name.

I tried using the function

```
occurences<-table(unlist(myrow))
occurences["Hospitals"]
```

but couldn't count the number of hospitals in the row.

The output should look like :

```
Hospitals : 8
Health campus: 1

Total Hospitals = 9
```

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example.  Pehaps you need `sum(names(occurences) == "Hospitals')`  Note that we don't know the structure of your data to help you

Comment: It's a row with strings in it.

Comment: Noticed that you have updated the description, but it would be better if you can provide somee example as we don't know your data or context.  Better would be `dput`

Comment: Also, based on the info, if you do `table(unlists(myrow))`, it should give the count of both 'Hospitals' and 'Health campus'. From there, just do `sum(occurences)` to get the 'Total'

Comment: Kindly see my edit. I have included my whole row in it. Thankyou.

Comment: @akrun This question involves string detection, whereas the other question does not. I don't believe it should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @PeerChristensen yes, I have reopened the question.

Comment: @PeerChristensen. At the time I dupe tagged, there was no reproducible example

Comment: But it is a dupe anyway

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to count the number of occurences of "Hospital" in each string and then take the sum.

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

strings <- c("X", "Royal.Perth.Hospital","X.1","X.2","Rockingham.General.Hospital")

strings %>% str_count("Hospital") %>% sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `grepl` to find occurrence of `"Hospital"` and `"Health.Campus"` and then combine them to find occurrence of both.

```
Hospitals <- sum(grepl("Hospital", occurences))
Health.Campus <- sum(grepl("Health.Campus", occurences))
Total <- Hospitals + Health.Campus
```

You might want to include `ignore.case = TRUE` in `grepl` if the words occur in both lower and upper case.

---

Instead of `grepl` you could also use `stringr::str_detect` in similar fashion.

```
Hospitals <- sum(stringr::str_detect(occurences, "Hospital"))
```